# What transmissions are interchangeable with a 2006 Chevrolet Silverado extended cab automatic 6lug truck?

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, silverado

What transmissions interchange with a 2006 Chevrolet Silverado extended cab automatic 6lug truck

Answer (score 0):

For the 2006, I think you can use earlier than that from about 2003-2006 4L60e transmission from either a Silverado or GMC Sierra 1500. Don't try to use the transmission out of a 2500, 2500HD, or 3500. If gasoline powered, these used primarily the 4L80e transmission, which is completely different. If they were diesel, I think they used Allison transmissions. You'll also want to ensure you get one which is out of a 4x4 if that is what you have, or 2wd. Swapping out between the two can be done, but it creates a lot of issues. 4L60e transmissions from other types of vehicles (they were widely used) may fit in place of the one you have, but will not run the same, because they aren't built the same.